# Android google map v2 polygon overlap issue

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

This is a screen capture of my sample Android app:

[image]

I have implemented a polygon on google map v2.

When a user draws the geometric figure and get an overlap region, the region border overlaps.

Is there any way to redraw the geometric figure and remove the point in the region?

Comment: You may want to compute the convex hull of your set of points. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull. Many algorithms and implementations are easily found on the Internet.

Comment: I found that convex hull can't use my case. Cause if I need to draw a geometric figure which like a cloud, the convex hull will connect all the point which at the outermost....